# alamofire parse nested json

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm new to swift, first time networking in swift use `alamofire`, and I had couple issues, I cant parse nested JSON from my API, its been 3 days and still figure it out what wrong with this issue, here example code

API :

```
    {
  "id" : "7fc8581a0373715c62750ba2c472d5d3",
  "status" : 1,
  "progress" : [
    {
      "state" : "3",
      "airline_code" : "SRI",
      "data" : {
        "go" : [
          {
            "additional" : {
              "numstop" : 0
            },
            "flights" : [
              {
                "flight_num" : "SJ231",
                "depart_port" : "JOG",
                "depart_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_city" : "Jakarta, Cengkareng",
                "extended_attribute" : {
                  "bus" : null,
                  "pro" : null,
                  "eco" : {
                    "id" : "6155a71e6fe687b54a97cba4de3091af",
                    "class_letter" : "g",
                    "seat_avail" : "2"
                  }
                },
                "depart_datetime" : "2018-05-05 11:00",
                "id" : "bebbdb13270a448ffa55ed2e928e2d60",
                "depart_city" : "Yogyakarta",
                "arrive_datetime" : "2018-05-05 12:10",
                "flight_duration" : "01:10",
                "arrive_time" : "12:10",
                "depart_time" : "11:00",
                "arrive_port" : "CGK"
              }
            ],
            "id" : "0d82983e6cbcbabd9dfea57c8622253a",
            "fares" : {
              "bus" : null,
              "pro" : null,
              "eco" : {
                "id" : "d06d8c19a5ad77089df538b8b54e5ac9",
                "by_ages" : {
                  "child" : null,
                  "infant" : null,
                  "adult" : {
                    "basic" : 330000,
                    "fuel" : 0,
                    "discount" : 0,
                    "adm" : 50000,
                    "iwjr" : 5000,
                    "surcharge" : 0,
                    "total" : 418000,
                    "tax" : 33000
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "additional" : {
              "numstop" : 0
            },
            "flights" : [
              {
                "flight_num" : "SJ235",
                "depart_port" : "JOG",
                "depart_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_city" : "Jakarta, Cengkareng",
                "extended_attribute" : {
                  "bus" : null,
                  "pro" : null,
                  "eco" : {
                    "id" : "d10c02b1fce3ef00d340faacfeebf155",
                    "class_letter" : "v",
                    "seat_avail" : "9"
                  }
                },
                "depart_datetime" : "2018-05-05 17:45",
                "id" : "ad185a29a9e6b302aa6d1b86e933f029",
                "depart_city" : "Yogyakarta",
                "arrive_datetime" : "2018-05-05 18:55",
                "flight_duration" : "01:10",
                "arrive_time" : "18:55",
                "depart_time" : "17:45",
                "arrive_port" : "CGK"
              }
            ],
            "id" : "8dd63fa4f7256a2ac00352519ae787d6",
            "fares" : {
              "bus" : null,
              "pro" : null,
              "eco" : {
                "id" : "436ab688a1e4512d41c95e55e2fdcdea",
                "by_ages" : {
                  "child" : null,
                  "infant" : null,
                  "adult" : {
                    "basic" : 360000,
                    "fuel" : 0,
                    "discount" : 0,
                    "adm" : 50000,
                    "iwjr" : 5000,
                    "surcharge" : 0,
                    "total" : 451000,
                    "tax" : 36000
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "additional" : {
              "numstop" : 0
            },
            "flights" : [
              {
                "flight_num" : "IN279",
                "depart_port" : "JOG",
                "depart_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
                "arrive_city" : "Jakarta, Cengkareng",
                "extended_attribute" : {
                  "bus" : {
                    "id" : "27bca993eb75f1ca3275f46b8229624e",
                    "class_letter" : "i",
                    "seat_avail" : "2"
                  },
                  "pro" : null,
                  "eco" : {
                    "id" : "933c24d214b8fd55d4237bf1e6eb5f6b",
                    "class_letter" : "g",
                    "seat_avail" : "3"
                  }
                },
                "depart_datetime" : "2018-05-05 19:20",
                "id" : "a0c3bd5f6194975cefae8240abef8754",
                "depart_city" : "Yogyakarta",
                "arrive_datetime" : "2018-05-05 20:30",
                "flight_duration" : "01:10",
                "arrive_time" : "20:30",
                "depart_time" : "19:20",
                "arrive_port" : "CGK"
              }
            ],
            "id" : "614836006a92c2deac59eeaef926cf1b",
            "fares" : {
              "bus" : {
                "id" : "865493da8066ac0c677cecfbb88e181b",
                "by_ages" : {
                  "child" : null,
                  "infant" : null,
                  "adult" : {
                    "basic" : 988000,
                    "fuel" : 0,
                    "discount" : 0,
                    "adm" : 50000,
                    "iwjr" : 5000,
                    "surcharge" : 0,
                    "total" : 1141800,
                    "tax" : 98800
                  }
                }
              },
              "pro" : null,
              "eco" : {
                "id" : "74802ef5e6bd5b93c016fcd98aa63925",
                "by_ages" : {
                  "child" : null,
                  "infant" : null,
                  "adult" : {
                    "basic" : 330000,
                    "fuel" : 0,
                    "discount" : 0,
                    "adm" : 50000,
                    "iwjr" : 5000,
                    "surcharge" : 0,
                    "total" : 418000,
                    "tax" : 33000
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "code" : null,
      "message" : null,
      "ctr" : "1",
      "rate" : 100
    }
  ]
}
```

here my code to parse it :

```
if let json = response.result.value {
let JSONData_child = JSON(json)
let progress = JSONData_child["progress"]
print(progess)
//heres the issue
let name = progress["data"][0]["go"]["flights"].string
if name != nil {
   print(name!)
}
//
     }
```

it can access nested "progress", but seems I can't access "data" nested JSON

all I wanted is access "flights" data from JSON,

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Not able to see `progress` key

Comment: im sorry, wait i update

Comment: edited @AnkitJayaswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the JSON response, date can be bundled in complex structure of `array` and `dictionary`:
>
> ```
> **Array:** (Comes in the bracket `[]`)
>
> **Dictionary:** (Comes in the bracket `{}`)
> ```

**Array:**

Array have different property to access object. Like:

To fetch objects at particular indexes, you can use `[0], [1], [2]... and so on`. Also can access specific indexes with `first, last`

**For example:**

```
let arr = [Any]()

arr.first // will give value at index 0
arr[0] // will give value of index 0
arr[1] // will give value of index 1
arr[2] // will give value of index 2
arr.last // will give value of last index
```

**Dictionary:**

Dictionary have key-value pairs. and you can access value with `dict["key"]`.

**For example:**

```
let dict = [String: Any]()
let value = dict["key"] // It will give the value for particular `key`
```

> **In your case:**

You can directly access the data if you are sure that json will not change. As:

`let name = progress[0]["data"]["go"][0]["flights"][0]`

It will give dictionary:

```
    {
        "flight_num" : "SJ231",
        "depart_port" : "JOG",
        "depart_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
        "arrive_timezone" : "Asia\/Jakarta",
        "arrive_city" : "Jakarta, Cengkareng",
        "extended_attribute" : {
            "bus" : null,
            "pro" : null,
            "eco" : {
                "id" : "6155a71e6fe687b54a97cba4de3091af",
                "class_letter" : "g",
                "seat_avail" : "2"
            }
        },
        "depart_datetime" : "2018-05-05 11:00",
        "id" : "bebbdb13270a448ffa55ed2e928e2d60",
        "depart_city" : "Yogyakarta",
        "arrive_datetime" : "2018-05-05 12:10",
        "flight_duration" : "01:10",
        "arrive_time" : "12:10",
        "depart_time" : "11:00",
        "arrive_port" : "CGK"
    }
```

Comment: btw whats [0] mean?

Comment: hey @AnkitJayaswal

Comment: `[0]` pulls the item at index 0 out of a collection. its the same as `myArray.first?`

Comment: @themasmul, I am updating my answer with explanation. Just give me some time

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal  can the [0] / index is dynamic? , cz i just got the last one of the array flight.

Comment: Yes `[0]` just like to `objectAtIndex(0)`. You can set `[1]` for first index, `[2], [3], [4]...`  and so on

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal how can i loop the index [0] ? because its not dynamic

Comment: @themasmul, I didn't get your point. What do you mean by `loop the index` ?